# Why does System.out.println(ray.set(1,93) ); return 5, not 93?

Tags: java

```
List<Integer> vals;
vals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
vals.add(23);
vals.add(11);
vals.set(1,5);
vals.add(4);
vals.set(0,7);
vals.add(53);
System.out.println(vals.set(1, 93));
```

When I run this, I get 5, rather than 93. On Oracle, the Modifier and Type section for Interface List shows as E. Can someone explain what E is and why it goes to 5 rather than 93?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-

Comment: Check the documentation: it returns the previous value of the element which is 5.

Comment: Change the question description as it is very specific to your problem. Try asking something generic. Consider these before asking your next question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask     

https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        vals.add(23); // 0-23, 
        vals.add(11); // 0-23, 1-11, 
        vals.set(1,5); // 0-23, 1-5,
        vals.add(4);  // 0-23, 1-5, 2-4
        vals.set(0,7); // 0-7, 1-5, 2-4
        vals.add(53); // 0-7, 1-5, 2-4, 3-53
        System.out.println(vals.set(1, 93));  // 0-7, 1-93, 2-4, 3-53
        // As previously at 1 position, element was 5. So 5 will be returned in above statement.
```

> When you call set method of ArrayList, it returns the the "**element previously at the specified position**".

Answer (score 0):

**set** function in ArrayList does returns the previous value and assigns the new value at the position you specified. Kindly see the Java documentation at
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)